# VBA How to identify if a column's contents is numerical?

Tags: database, vba, excel, numeric

I have got a qestion regarding Excel VBA. I have to perform this task automatically.
Is there any possibility to check whether an entire column's contents (not talking about a cell format) is numerical (containing only numbers)? Of course, I know that an alternative way is avaible, i.e. going down cell by cell. 
I know that a set filter can identify whether the column is numerical. How to get this information via VBA?

Comment: What have you tried so far? you have highlighted an alternate solution but not told us what you have tried so far. As a starting point, have a look at **Regular Expressions** in vba

Answer (score 3):

COUNT counts numbers; COUNTA counts numbers and text.

```
=Count(A:A)=CountA(A:A)
```

... returns true if column A contains numbers only. In VBA as,

```
Debug.Print CBool(Application.Count(Columns(1))=Application.CountA(Columns(1)))
```

To convert text-that-looks-like-numbers to true numbers, use TextToColumns, Fixed width, Finish on the column.

```
 Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for answers; however, it still doesn't get me to the point. There are numbers in this column that ARE NOT numbers for Excel (formatting issue). I am wondering how to convert it automatically. I know that I can do that using PasteSpecial method (cell value + '0'), but don't know how to omit that for texts (prevent from adding to strings). The second issue is how to get '0' value automatically, without distubring workbook arrangement.

Comment: Use TextToColumns, Fixed width, Finish on the column.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution I can thing of:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell  As Range
    Dim myCol   As Range

    Set myCol = Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Cells.SpecialCells(2)

    For Each myCell In myCol.Cells
        If Not IsNumeric(myCell) Then
            Debug.Print myCell.Address
            Exit For
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

As a next step, try writing a boolean function, that takes the worksheet and the column to search for. It can be of use.