# Column format converted to Number, but showing as text

Tags: vba, excel

Ive a sheet which is generated using ADO select statement from another sheet. So I have to manually set some formatting. So here is the way I did.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice")
    .Columns(1).Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mmm"
    .Columns(6).Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
    .Columns(10).Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "0.00"
End With
```

Here column 1 and 6 am converting into two date formats. and column 10 I need to convert into Number format. But 1 and 6 converts fine. But 10 still showing as text and so alligned on left side. Screen grab disabled on our PC, otherwise I could share my actual screen. Hope its clear.

Comment: Excel may not see changes if you programmatically set a cell value as a string object. Try `cell.value = cdbl(cell.value)` to explicitly cast a value.

Comment: Im not setting up the values manually.. Instead am using ADO and select the columns from another sheet and paste into this invoice sheet. But Column 1 and 6 working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse it as `General` first using `TextToColumns` then apply your formatting. Something like below should work:

```
With .Columns(10).Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                   FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1) 
                   'DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                   'FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1)         
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
End with
```

Or as @Whome commented, if it is all numbers, then you can simply:

```
With .Columns(10).Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
    .Value2 = .Value2      
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
End with
```

**Edit1:** Explained 1st code above. Using `.Range("A1")` as destination takes advantage of the `Range.Range` notation in Excel VBA. This means that you can re-index (not sure if this is the right term) a `Range` using *Range Objects* `Range` method. For example:

```
Dim r As Range: Set r = Range("B1:C10")
Debug.Print r.Range("A1").Address '/* this gives you $B$1 */
Degug.Print r.Range("B5").Address '/* this gives you $C$5 */
```

**Illustration:**

[image]

And applying that logic in your example:

```
.Columns(10).Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0) '/* refers to J2:J1048576 */
```

And `Range("A1")` of that range (or Cells(1) as Jeeped commented) is `$J$2`.

For your second inquiry, please refer to @Jeeped's comment:

> "Sandeep brings up a valid point with his second inquiry. If you aren't going to force all delimiter parameters to false, perhaps DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1) would be better. You never know what has been left by the user in terms of TextToColumns delimiter(s) parameters."

Comment: Good to see that you got `.Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)` in the right order.

Comment: Thats great man.. It works perfectly... But I didnt understand that .Range("A1") there.. can you explain a little whats that means.. I am a very beginner with VBA. And also why xlDelimited datatype there even its not Delimitted string..

Comment: @SandeepThomas Then use code number 2 :), Just kidding, I will post an edit to explain.

Comment: @SandeepThomas - It isn't the top-left (A1) cell on the worksheet; it is the top-left cell *within* J2:J1048576 which is J2 on the worksheet. It could also have been `.cells(1)` which might have been marginally less confusing.

Comment: @L42 - Sandeep brings up a valid point with his second inquiry. If you aren't going to force all delimiter parameters to false, perhaps `DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)` would be better. You never know what has been left by the user in terms of TextToColumns delimiter(s) parameters. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48149431/vba-how-to-identify-if-a-columns-contents-is-numerical/48149553#48149553).

Comment: @Jeeped Yeah exactly. Was reviewing documentation before answering that and since you pointed it out already, I just point OP to your comment :D.

Comment: btw you explained it great.. thanks...also thank you @Jeeped for that clarification for my question..