# in excel VBA check if any cells in a range is text then do something in the cell adjacent to the 1st cell only

Tags: excel, vba, range

```
    Dim LR As Long                              'Last Row
    Dim Leveli As Long                          'WBS Level / Activity Level counter
    Dim Funci As Long                           'WBS Range that covers all WBS and activities below a certain WBS
    Dim FRR As Long                             '1st Row of the WBS Range
    Dim LRR As Long                             'Last Row of the WBS Range
    Dim MyCell As Range                         'The Cell Identifying the subject WBS Level / Activity which need to determine its range
   'Determining the Last Row
LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Determine the 1st & last rows for the range covered by each WBS level
    For Leveli = 3 To LR
        Set MyCell = Range("B" & Leveli)
            If IsNumeric(MyCell.Value) Then
                For Funci = Leveli + 1 To LR
                    If Range("C" & Funci).Value > Range("C" & Leveli).Value Then
                        LRR = Funci
                        FRR = Leveli + 1
                     Else: Exit For
                    End If
                Next Funci
'For the identified range covered by the WBS, check if all cells in this range are WBS levels as well, then no need to show this level "H", otherwise will keep it visible to user "K"
                   If Application.WorksheetFunction.And(IsNumber(Range("B" & FRR & ":B" & LRR))) Then
                   MyCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "H"
                   Else: MyCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "K"
                   End If
'                 Next
            End If
    Next Leveli
```

Guys, the planners & schedulers will defenately know this as this is a schedule.

The above is part of a code which is dealing with a hierarchy levels (WBS levels) where level 1 is the highest and all other levels and activities under each level lies under it, under each level there're other levels and / or activities (activities are the lowest thing in the hierarchy system).

Under column "B", against each row it's written either a number (identifying the WBS level of this row) or the word "Activity" identifying that this row represent an activity, and by default if you see activity for example, you need to see the row above to know that this activity is under level 3 - for instance - and in the next row above you'll see that both are under levle 2 and so on.

for each "Leveli" I check if the cell ("B"&Leveli) contains number, then it's a WBS level, accordingly i'm looping to determin this WBS is covering how much range below it (it could cover some activities only, or activities & other WBSs under it which will have higher numeric number in column B), then and here's the issue, I simply want to check if all cells in the range covered by this precise WBS are numeric (it means that no activities appears under it) then I want to write the character "H" (for Hide) as this WBS I don't want it to appear to the user (the "H" should be written in the same row of this WBS but adjacent to column B), however, if even one cell in that range is text (Activity), then I want the character to be "K" (for Keep).

There's something wrong with the statement "If Application.WorksheetFunction.And(IsNumber(Range("B" & FRR & ":B" & LRR)))"  it gives me "*Sub or Function not defined*" (see attached pic).

please help me fix it.

Comment: Your immediate problem is that there is no `IsNumber` function in VBA ... I think you mean to use [IsNumeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function) or maybe `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber` ... either way, you might also want to check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48149431/vba-how-to-identify-if-a-columns-contents-is-numerical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`And(IsNumber(...))` works well as a worksheet formula. But it doesn't work in VBA. You can use UDF to obtain the same result.

```vb
Sub YourCode()
...
    ' Call UDF bIsNum, the return is boolean
    If bIsNum(Range("B" & FRR & ":B" & LRR)) Then
        MyCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "H"
    Else: MyCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "K"
    End If
...
End Sub

Function bIsNum(rRange As Range) As Boolean
    Dim c as Range
    For Each c In rRange
        If Not VBA.IsNumeric(c) Then
            bIsNum = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    bIsNum = True
End Function
```

Comment: sorry, but what's "c"? should I define variable? I'm still not familiar with VBA functions

Comment: In theory, you should define variable before using. But it works w/o definition in VBA. Just try the code.

Comment: I hand to declare variable & it worked perfectly... thank you so much